# How to write to csv dict in one line

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary {k1:1, k2:2, k3:3 } How can I write it to csv in this form
[|k1|1|k2|2|k3|3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iY3A.png)
Already tried all the options, the maximum that happened
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX2DC.png)

Comment: Please post your best attempt and we can work off of that.

Comment: Do you really want it written as a .png mimicing a visual spreadsheet? Or perhaps a series of text lines with comma separated values? Or was it the Pipe separated example? Posting the result you want as text helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
def write_to_csv_one_line(dictionary, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(','.join([','.join(item) for item in dictionary.items()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSV writer and the Python `chain()` function as follows:

```
from itertools import chain
import csv

my_dict = {"k1" : 1, "k2" : 2, "k3" : 3}

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv.writer(f_output).writerow(chain.from_iterable(my_dict.items()))
```

Giving an output of:

```
k1,1,k2,2,k3,3
```